# Multiple ul tab elements with js not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs

I am trying to make multiple ul tab elements, using java to display the different tabs.
This works fine, as long as i only have one ul element for the tabs. When i create a new ul for new tabs, this will not work.

So i am trying to make two ul elements each with 3 tabs. When the page is loaded, the first ul element with tabs loads fine, but the second ul element is not working.

Please take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X6X5p/) to view the code i am using and see the problem i encounter.

My guess is, that the problem might have something to do with the following:

```
for ( var id in tabLinks ) {
    tabLinks[id].onclick = showTab;
    tabLinks[id].onfocus = function() { this.blur() };
    if ( i == 0 ) tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';
    i++; }
```

The script can somehow not load two ul elements on the same page. All help appreciated.

Best regards,
Patrick

Comment: did you really meant java or is it javascript?

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing that out.. Its not the first time that has happened to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have two elements with the same ID (in this case two `ul` with ID `tabs`). All selectors and events will be applied to the first element only, which is why only the first tab set works.

Comment: Hi An,

I tried making the same js code, but using the ID tabs2 instead, and the same in the html code, however this does still not seem to work.

Comment: Hi An,

I see :) However, only one of them is showing the content, and both should be showing content at the same time. Does this have anything to do with the function showtab()?

Comment: Sorry, I can't really inspect the code right now. What I'd suggest is rewriting the function, take a class name instead of ID's.